# Storing the path geometry and changing it later

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I am using WPF shapes to render some geometry. I save the rendered geometry of the shapes and add them later. Now the thing is that I want someone to be able to change the geometry object like increasing height and width of the shape.

I know a way where I can update the string and assign it back to the geometry object to update it.

Is there any alternate or better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple Example for Ellipse properties:**

```
<Path Fill="Gold" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="{Binding RadiusX}" RadiusY="50" />
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

And in your ViewModel (or `DataContext` if you are not using the **MVVM design pattern**) define a property (Either Notifiable using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` or a `DependencyProperty`) that has the name `RadiusX`. now when you change it , it should update your geometry display.

**This can also be done for a Path Geometry :**

For that you will have to one of 2 thing:

1) have a property of type `PathGeometry` as explained above and use it regularly:

```
<Path Data="{Binding PointsForPath}"/>
```

2) have another data structure that holds your points the way you want, and then use a converter,which will take your points and return a `PathGeomerty` element:

```
<Path Data="{Binding Path=PointsForPath, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PointsConverter}}"/>
```

**For Saving your path:**

if you are using an SQL Server (or similar), you have the option of storing a geometry as a special column in your table, for more information on that:
[SQL Geomerty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx)

Let me know if you need further assistance regarding the terms used in the answer:

- `ViewModel`
- `DataContext`
- `Binding`
- `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Xaml serialization.

From [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590439.aspx):

```
// Create the Xaml.
Button originalButton = new Button();
originalButton.Height = 50;
originalButton.Width = 100;
originalButton.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
originalButton.Content = "Click Me";

// Save the Button to a string. 
string savedButton = XamlWriter.Save(originalButton);

// Load the button
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedButton);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
Button readerLoadButton = (Button)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Note that there a [some limitations to Xaml serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx#Realistic_Scenarios_for_Use_of_XAMLWriter_Save) but as far as I can see saving and loading geometries is fine.